# Check username and password in Login Form (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use jQuery to check username and password in Login form. I use GET method. Doing so well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you should use POST with SSL. If you use GET, the password will be sent in clear in the URL and potentially logged on all intermediate internet routers, proxies, ...

Comment: Tran, Darin is correct. Here's an example using jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271880/jquery-ajax-login-form/1271997#1271997